# Deleting tabs dynamically in Wicket AjaxTabbedPanel

Tags: java, wicket

I have a problem related to dynamic deletion of tabs in an AjaxTabbedPanel. It is related to the auto selection of another tab when you delete the current tab. While it works fine deleting the last tab and any tab in between it fails when you try to delete the first tab. It seems setSelectedTab(0) does nothing as its already the selected tab (even though the actual tab is in fact deleted). Deleting the first tab will show as if the second tab is selected, but the contents are that of the one that was just deleted.

Anyone have a good rewrite for this piece of code below that works for all tabs?

```
private class DeleteLink extends AjaxLink<Section> {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public DeleteLink(String id, IModel<Section> model) {
    super(id, model);
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

    // add tabbed panel to target refresh
    if(target != null) {
      target.add(getPage().get("container"));
    }

    Section section = getModelObject();
    Form form = section.getForm();          
    form.deleteSection(section);

    TabbedPanel<ITab> tabPanel = findParent(TabbedPanel.class);
    if (tabPanel != null) {
      int index = tabPanel.getSelectedTab();
      if(index > 0)
        tabPanel.setSelectedTab(index-1);
      else
        tabPanel.setSelectedTab(index);
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried selecting index+1 and that will show the correct content, but it then renders the tabs as if the tab after is selected. (So deleting first tab, will show content of second tab, but third tab is selected).

Comment: As an extra "challenge" I wonder how I can dynamically select the tab that was just added to an AjaxTabbedPanel. I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException if I try to select the index of the newly added one. Seems like a classic problem of the model growing, but the UI component does not know that before after it has rendered the model once. Likely my problem above is linked to the same issues.

Comment: Your implementation is not clear. I have tested your behavior with default example (http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/tabbed-panel) and it's work fine (only deletion of the last element causes IndexOutOfBoundException, but it's about another issue). I've added "add" and "delete" ajax links to simple container and changed list of tabs dynamicly, updating tabbed panel via ajax. From your example it is not clear what is the Section class and where is actual tabs deletion is processed. setSelectedTab ( 0 ) must work correctly.